# Repeat Array javascript value and create index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know how to repeat an array with another array based on the first value. When create a new array how to add an index for each row.
Example:

```
Table Base
Total | Item | Description   | Price
5     | 946  | T-Shirt Red   | $10
3     | 456  | T-Shirt Black | $12
2     | 489  | T-Shirt Blue  | $11.50

Table Result
Index | Total | Item | Description   | Price
1     | 5     | 946  | T-Shirt Red   | $10
2     | 5     | 946  | T-Shirt Red   | $10
3     | 5     | 946  | T-Shirt Red   | $10
4     | 5     | 946  | T-Shirt Red   | $10
5     | 5     | 946  | T-Shirt Red   | $10
1     | 3     | 456  | T-Shirt Black | $12
2     | 3     | 456  | T-Shirt Black | $12
3     | 3     | 456  | T-Shirt Black | $12
1     | 2     | 489  | T-Shirt Blue  | $11.50
2     | 2     | 489  | T-Shirt Blue  | $11.50
```

I made this code, but I don't know how to make it work.

```js
var data = [[5,946,'T-Shirt Red',10],[3,456,'T-Shirt Black',12],[2,489,'T-Shirt Blue',11.50]];
var items = [];
var i, j;

for(i in data){
    for (j = 1; j <= data[i][0]; j++) {
    items.push([j,data[i]]);
  }
}

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern browsers, it's a simple change

```
items.push([j, ...data[i]]);
```

for supporting IE, you'd need to change that to

```
items.push([j].concat(data[i]));
```

```js
var data = [[5,946,'T-Shirt Red',10],[3,456,'T-Shirt Black',12],[2,489,'T-Shirt Blue',11.50]];
var items = [];
var i, j;

for(i in data){
    for (j = 1; j <= data[i][0]; j++) {
    items.push([j,...data[i]]);
  }
}
items.forEach(item => console.log(item.join('\t| ')))
```